# SQL INSERT INTO auto put ID

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

i just have 50k + SQL queries like this:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_posts` (`ID`, `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_title`, `post_excerpt`, `post_status`, `comment_status`, `ping_status`, `post_password`, `post_name`, `to_ping`, `pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`, `post_content_filtered`, `post_parent`, `guid`, `menu_order`, `post_type`, `post_mime_type`, `comment_count`) VALUES
(357, 1, '2016-06-03 16:35:24', '2016-06-03 16:35:24', 'SOME CONTENT HERE', 'Artykuły', '', 'trash', 'closed', 'closed', '', 'artykuly__trashed', '', '', '2016-06-03 20:52:06', '2016-06-03 20:52:06', '', 0, '038;p=357', 0, 'autoblog_artykuly', '', 0);

(...)

INSERT INTO `wp_posts` (`ID`, `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_title`, `post_excerpt`, `post_status`, `comment_status`, `ping_status`, `post_password`, `post_name`, `to_ping`, `pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`, `post_content_filtered`, `post_parent`, `guid`, `menu_order`, `post_type`, `post_mime_type`, `comment_count`) VALUES
(357, 1, '2016-06-03 16:35:24', '2016-06-03 16:35:24', 'SOME CONTENT HERE', 'Artykuły', '', 'trash', 'closed', 'closed', '', 'artykuly__trashed', '', '', '2016-06-03 20:52:06', '2016-06-03 20:52:06', '', 0, '38;p=357', 0, 'autoblog_artykuly', '', 0);
```

All queries have the same ID and when i try to add this to database via phpmyadmin i get this information:

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '357' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

With what change ID: 357 to put auto values? AUTO INCREMENT?

Comment: Yes, change the column to `AUTOINCREMENT` and don't supply an `ID` value.

Answer (score 1):

You should set up the ID to be [UNIQUE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp) and [AUTO-INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) and remove it from the INSERT-statement. You should never have to worry about the ID, it should be handled by MySQL itself.

```
INSERT INTO `wp_posts` (`post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_title`, `post_excerpt`, `post_status`, `comment_status`, `ping_status`, `post_password`, `post_name`, `to_ping`, `pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`, `post_content_filtered`, `post_parent`, `guid`, `menu_order`, `post_type`, `post_mime_type`, `comment_count`) VALUES
(1, '2016-06-03 16:35:24', '2016-06-03 16:35:24', 'SOME CONTENT HERE', 'Artykuły', '', 'trash', 'closed', 'closed', '', 'artykuly__trashed', '', '', '2016-06-03 20:52:06', '2016-06-03 20:52:06', '', 0, '038;p=357', 0, 'autoblog_artykuly', '', 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your error display you set primary key in table design time so that this error occurs. If you want to set auto-increment, then you just set UNIQUE INDEX on a column.